# Include .NET Framework to setup

Tags: .net, installation, frameworks, include, offline

I'm creating an installation for a WPF-application with a simple "Setup Project". At the window with the prerequisites-settings I'm choosing "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 und x64)" and that the required components are in the same directory as the application because I need an offline installation.

Now I've put the .NET-Installation-file in every possible directory...
- in the application directory
- in the setup-directory
- in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX452
- in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX452\de
... but nothing works.

I always get this error:

### Original (german):

ERROR: Um "Erforderliche Komponenten von demselben Speicherort wie die Anwendung herunterladen" im Dialogfeld "Erforderliche Komponenten" aktivieren zu können, muss die Datei "DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-DEU.exe" für das Element "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 und x64)" auf den lokalen Computer heruntergeladen werden. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.

### Translated by myself (english):

Error: To activate "download required components from the same directory as the application", the file "DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-DEU.exe" for the element "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 und x64)" has to bie downloaded on your computer. You can find further information here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.

How can I include the .NET Framework offline installation to my setup?